# Integer solutions for $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}+\frac{1}{xyz}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Is there a beautiful solution for this equation over the integers?

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}+\frac{1}{xyz}=1$$

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%2Byz%2Bxz%2Bx%2By%2Bz%2B1%3Dxyz+over+integers) gives many solutions, e.g. $x=-9, y=z=2$.  Or, if you prefer positive values, $x=3, y=4, z=5$.

Comment: By beautiful solution, I was specifically referring to a general solution without using mathematical software. But alfa also gives $z=0$, which is a false root. Is there a compact solution using elementarey algebra or number theory?

Comment: So this is $xyz-(xy+xz+yz)-(x+y+z)=1$, I guess? Not that this helps much, I don't think

Comment: "By beautiful solution, I was specifically referring to a general solution without using mathematical software." Then please edit the question to say so.

Comment: Eh, I think it's clear enough

Comment: For nonzero integers, the equation is equivalent to $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)=2(x+y+z)$, which might be relevant here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde -- Concise, compact general solution not using any brute force method.

Comment: @Paul -- How did you come to that equivalence? And it can't be equivalent because it also gives the solution $z=0,$ which does not satisfy the original equation.

Comment: @Parseval, "for nonzero integers."  I was just trying different ways to factor the terms, or something like it

Comment: @Parseval, all the algebra people are doing assumes that $x,y,z$ are all nonzero.  This is a very minor issue.

Comment: @Paul I am sorry : wrong addressing ; it was for parseval but he has erased his remark.

Comment: $(-n,n-1,1), n\leq 2$ are  all negative solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)=1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{xz}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{xyz}\color{red}{=1+1=2}$$

Rewriting $1+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x+1}{x}$ and mutliplying both sides by $xyz$ (assumed nonzero), we get $$(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)=2xyz$$
Now, $x,y,z$ are all integers, so this gives a lot of conditions.  For example, if we take $z=5$, we have $$(x+1)(y+1)6=10xy$$
or $$3(x+1)(y+1)=5xy$$
Hence, either $x$ or $y$ is a multiple of $3$.  Also, either $x+1$ or $y+1$ is a multiple of $5$.  Assume that we have $x=3k, y+1=5m$, so we rewrite as
$$3(3k+1)5m=5(3k)(5m-1)$$
Cancelling, we get $$(3k+1)m=k(5m-1)$$
If $m=1$, then $3k+1=4k$, so $k=1$, which gives $(x,y,z)=(3,4,5)$.
If $m=2$, then $6k+2=9k$, so $k=2/3$, which gives $(x,y,z)=(2,9,5)$.
If $m=3$, then $9k+3=14k$, so $k=3/5$, which does not give an integer solution.

Etc, etc, we can find as many solutions as we want by trial and error.

Comment: This is great, thank you!

Comment: Good stuff here!  @Parseval, The one comment I want to make is that it is also easy to show that there are only finitely many solutions such that $x,y,z$ are all **positive** integers. WLOG $x\le y\le z$. If $4\le x$ then $(1+1/x)(1+1/y)(1+1/z)\le (5/4)^3<2$ which is a contradiction. OTOH if $x=2$ or $x=3$ we get in the same way an upper  bound for $y$. But $z$ and $y$ determine $z$ uniquely so we are done. $(2,4,15)$, $(2,5,9)$, $(2,6,7)$, $(3,3,8)$, $(3,4,5)$ are all the triples (unless I made a mistake).

Comment: So there are infinitely many solutions if you also count the negative integers?

Comment: That seems to be the case. And there was a typo in the first triple: $z$ should have been $15$, now corrected.

Comment: Alpha gives a range for x between -10 and 10. So the restriction that the upper bound for x is 3, can't be true?

Comment: Are you sure about that @Parseval? Remember that $x$ is *the smallest* of the three variables. Check what happens if you add the constraint $z\ge y\ge x$.

Comment: Where in the problem is that constraint given?